# Swift - scrollViewDidScroll not getting called

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a view controller which is extending to table view. In viewDidLoad of view controller, I am setting delegate and datasource of table view as self. In storyboard, on the table view I have isScrollEnabled set to true.

Still the scroll view delegate methods are not being called. UITableView related methods works fine.

Is there anything else I need to be doing?

***Custom class:***

```
class MyCustomClass: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
        tableView.scrollsToTop = true

        tableView.isHidden = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }
}

extension MyCustomClass: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
   // UITableView related methods i.e. cellForRow, numberOfRows, didSelectRow...

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        log.debug("start scroll")
        isScrolling = true
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        isScrolling = false
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if isScrollDown == false {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: that's not possible unless you have a problem in your scrolling enable disable properties,   try to  remove every method of scroll view add just scrollViewDidScroll and also remove code for enable / disable scrolling

Comment: There's no reason, given the code you show that the delegate methods shouldn't have been called. There's no need to move the code to viewDidAppear, or awakeFromNib, or to cast the table view to UIScrollView. The fact that your selection isn't working suggests that the delegate isn't set. Is self.tableView non-nil? Did you set the data source in IB possibly? Are you sure that your delegate methods are spelled correctly

Comment: I think you have to extend the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol